# SOQL Injection Issue

Tags: apex, soql, batch, soql-injection

I am working on an assignment where I need to fix a SOQL Injection issue in one of the SOQL in a batch apex. The query is below.

```
SELECT Id, Name from Contact where (TrustName__c != null OR Status__c != null OR Title != null OR City__c !- null or Street__c != null or State__c != null) AND Id in (SELECT Contact__c from PP__c)
```

However, I am not sure how this SOQL was flagged as a vulnerable query since it is not querying a specific field with a LIKE or something like that.

Can someone clarify? If this is a vulnerable query, how do I re-write the query?

Comment: We would need to see more context. Obviously, there's nothing here that should cause a problem, unless the source of the query is untrusted.

Comment: I see a typo with `City__c !- null`, but no possible way soql injection could happen. There is no user input!

Comment: @stackasaur, sorry that typo is by me. Please ignore that.

Comment: @sfdcfox, thanks for your response. During some time of the contact update in our system, the child record PP__c is created with very minimal information though it has more fields. The above query is used in a nightly batch apex to identify the list of PP__c records with Contact and each PP__c record is cloned and then populated with the information from Contact. The existing PP__c records cannot be updated due to complaince issue. So, new PP__c records are created every night and then populated with more info from Contact.

Comment: Is there a way to re-write the batch apex without using Database.getQueryLocator() method?

Comment: "Yes", but then you're limited to 50,000 records. That's probably not enough. However, Database.getQueryLocator can use an inline query instead of a String. This would be the preferred way to do the query.